# How to remove the end of a URL

Tags: url, google-search-console

I am getting this http://www.rigelnetworks.com/service/internet-marketing/javascript url in Google webmaster but don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Well, click on it maybe?

Comment: What do you want to resolve about it?

Comment: Remove all those `href="javascript:"` and `href="javascript"` links form your page?

Answer (score 0):

If I look at this page:
http://www.rigelnetworks.com/service/internet-marketing.

I can see plenty of link like this one in the source code:

```
<a title="Featured Technologies" href="javascript"><span>Featured Technologies</span></a>
```

It's just a simple string creating a new URL, not a javascript call.
Maybe you should consider removing all those creepy link.

Comment: please can let me know how do i remove these creepy link.

Comment: The problem is in your top menu.
All links written in red "featured verticals", "verticals", "services" , ... are wrap in those broken links.
I don't know specifically how you can remove them.

Comment: sorry! This is not coming from you top menu but from an hidden menu (called hidden-desktop in the code) at the same place at the top. here it is : http://i39.tinypic.com/20a4d9c.png
You might want to disable it.